# dynamic sql query error due to invalid character

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a dynamic  query  inside a package like :

```
 QUERY_STR := 'SELECT DISTINCT :1 
             FROM schema_name.'||  P_TABLE_NAME||' where UPPER(:2) NOT  IN (SELECT UPPER(LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_CODE)
from XX_LOOKUP_EXT LOOKUP_STG where UPPER(:3)=upper(LOOKUP_CODE)
and LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_TYPE=''' || P_LOOKUP_TYPE || ''') ;';
```

which i am trying to execute by

```
declare

    P_TABLE_NAME  varchar2(100):='XXHR_STG';
    P_LOOKUP_TYPE varchar2(100):='PER_SUPERVISOR_TYPE';
    p_column      VARCHAR2(100):='manager_type';

begin
XX_LOOKUP_VALIDATION.XX_VALIDATION_LOOKUP(P_TABLE_NAME,P_LOOKUP_TYPE,p_column);


end;
```

Actually in the query_str the p_lookup_type should be in quotes something like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT  manager_type 
FROM schema_name.XXHR_STG
 where UPPER(MANAGER_TYPE) NOT IN 
(SELECT UPPER(LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_CODE)
from XX_LOOKUP_EXT LOOKUP_STG where UPPER(MANAGER_TYPE)=upper(LOOKUP_CODE)
and LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_TYPE='PER_SUPERVISOR_TYPE';
```

But on calling the package i am getting an invalid character error

```
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
```

dbms output :

```
SELECT DISTINCT  :1 
FROM schema_name.XXHR_STG
 where UPPER(:2) NOT IN 
(select UPPER(LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_CODE)
from XX_LOOKUP_EXT LOOKUP_STG where UPPER(:3)=UPPER(LOOKUP_CODE)
and LOOKUP_STG.LOOKUP_TYPE='PER_SUPERVISOR_TYPE';
```

Comment: put a dbms_output.put_line to show the value of QUERY_STR before you pass or open the cursor. that will show what Oracle is trying to execute

Comment: What is the error that you get?  If you are trying to execute `query_str` via `execute immediate` by treating `:1`, `:2`, and `:3` as bind variables, that won't work.  Bind variables have to be variables not column names.

Comment: @kevinsky  - I have edited my question to answer these things. Thanks

Comment: @JustinCave edited the error as well

Comment: The actual error is either because of the colons in :1, :2 and :3 which you can't use, as Justin has already said; or the semicolon you have on the end. That statement separator should not be there for a dynamic statement. Not sure which it's complaining about first.

Comment: If you expect `:1`, `:2`, and `:3` to be bind variables, you can't do that.  Bind variables have to be values not column names.  You'd have to put the column names in the dynamic SQL string that you are building.

Comment: @JustinCave- Its is actually giving the coorect query even when i am passing the column names but still and identifier error is coming. Same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved . I had written ";" at the end of the dynamic query. Which souldnt be the case